# Why is PHP's move_uploaded_file() method returning false in my script?

Tags: php, html, file, forms, upload

I'm building a page that allows files to be uploaded to the server, and sorted. I know this code, even if it was working, isn't fit to be live, it was just a first draft to get the mechanics working since I'm quite new to server-side scripting.

Anyway, here's the upload-form page:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<center>
<h1>Please enter the details of the file you would like to upload:</h1><br/> 


    <table> 
    <tr>
    <td align='center'> 
    <form action='uploader.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'><b>Name:</b> </td> 
    <td align='left'><input type='text' name='name' maxlength='255' />
    </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
    <td align='center'><b>Description of file uploaded: </b>
    </td> 
    <td align='left'><textarea name='description' rows='5' cols='20'></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
    <td align='center'><b>Category: </b>
    </td> 

    <td align='left'> 
    <select name='category'> 
    <option value='1'>Agriculture</option>
    <option value='2'>Sexual Health</option>
    <option value='3'>Arithmetic</option>
    <option value='4'>Technology</option>
    <option value='5'>Reading/Literature</option>
    <option value='6'>Health/Medicine</option>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td align ='center' >
    <b>File: </b>
    </td>
    <td align='left'>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    <Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr height='20px'></tr> 

    <tr align ='left'>
    <td> </td>
    <td>
    <input type='Submit' value='Upload File' /> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table> 

</center>

<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the action page uploader.php:

```
<?php

$target_path = "./audio/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path) )  {
    echo "The file " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

Whenever I try to test this, on my localhost ( using XAMPP ) It echos "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"

And every few times it also says: " 
Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile in C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\uploader.php on line 5 "

But I can't see what's wrong with that argument? isn't uploadedfile defined as the temporary name for the file in my form?

Can you tell me what I've done wrong here?

Thanks a lot for

Comment: What do your permissions look like?

Comment: the folder is on my local machine and there doesn't seem to be any special constraints on the folder.

Comment: When an error occurs, you can use $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] and check what's going on exactly (my guess is that you're moving the file to nonexisting directory). Consult php.net on how to interpret error messages when dealing with file uploads.

Comment: The error I keep running into is "Undefined index: uploadedfile" I thought the form added the file to this array for me... am i supposed to be adding it myself somewhere?

Comment: Even better, *always* check whether or not `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK` and act accordingly on error (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: I'm accessing the page via http://localhost and then filling in the form as a user would...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: your HTML is invalid, causing the `form` element being closed prematurely.

There's no `</form>` end tag, so it's inserted at the next appropriate point, i.e.

```
<td align='center'>
  <form action='uploader.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <b>Name:</b>
  </form> <!-- <- here -->
</td>
```

Doing so, the file input element with name `uploadedfile` is outside of the form and never gets send to `uploader.php`. To correct this issue, move the start tag outside of your `table`, add the end tag near the end of `body` and remove the `<` before `Choose a file …`.

There are a couple of other validating errors, but I'll leave it to you to repair those. Next time, please serve your HTML to W3C's [validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) (you can do this automatically using Chris Pederick's [Web Developer toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)) and/or look at Firebug's/Chrome's web inspector and look at the `form` element (and what it contains).

Comment: Thank you very much this was indeed the problem! I just assumed it was the PHP since I was so new to it! 
One thing though... I've been testing this script now that it functions... and it still causes errors when I upload .mp3 files. 
I thought it was just a size problem, but even <1mb audio files can't be uploaded. 
is 'file' supposed to encompass audio? O.o

Comment: @Paul: that shouldn't cause any problem; the only thing I see is that your pasted code contains a maximum file size rule <100,000 bytes (≠ 1 Mb). As said earlier, *always* check the status of the `'error'` segment of the file array against the values on http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php and you'll know if something (and *what*) went wrong (e.g., `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE`).

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be calling the function correctly and using it in the correct context.

As far as the documentation is concerned there are two instances in which false can be returned from the `move_uploaded_file` function:

> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

We can assume this isn't the case because we're using the `tmp_name` element from our file in the `$_FILES` array.

> If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

So it must be something to do with this *catch all*.  I'd suggest turning `display_errors` on so we can see the warning that's generated.

Comment: I think it goes wrong in an earlier place, because of the error ‘Undefined index: uploadedfile’ in `$_FILES`.

Comment: the erros I get are : Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile in C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\uploader.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile in C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\uploader.php on line 10

Answer (score 1):

`if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] != 0)`  will give you the possible reasons for an error.
Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php for the error codes

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this should be a comment. Even more, as you can see above, I already posted a comment to the question with this message (and yes, I know you can't post a comment on someone else's question if your rep is below 50).

Comment: hmm, when I do this I get an extra error: 

Notice: Undefined variable: target_path in C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\uploader.php on line 10